# Importing cert and pkey to jks file

Tags: ssl, openssl, keytool, grizzly, jks

We have an application1 that is working with openssl and have a pkey and cert file (RSA) that clients are able to connect (handshake complete).

We have another application2 that does not use openssl but Java keytool and jks file. Client are not able to connect to this application (negotiation fails). We thought that the reason has to do with the fact that clients need to negotiate with application1's pkey and cert, so we added them to the jks file (using the procedure here http://blog.jgc.org/2011/06/importing-existing-ssl-keycertificate.html). - maybe we should have split it to two entries - one in the trust file and one in the keystore file.
Now application2 (uses Grizzly framework) fails to initiate and have the following exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: KeyManagerFactoryImpl is not initialized.
We are using jdk1.7.

Can anyone help?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Is the private key used by the client to authenticate itself to the server? Or does the private key belong to the server? What does application1 have to do with anything? That's just confusing the issue. Describe the problem, clearly, without extraneous info.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the very same error with Grizzly, on Java 7.

I used `SSLContextConfigurator` to setup my SSL configuration:

`SSLContextConfigurator sslContext= new SSLContextConfigurator();`

You can specify a number of properties, one of them is the key manager factory algorithm. Now if you do not specify it a default is picked, in my case `SunX509`. This implementation was available on my classpath, nevertheless I got this exception.

My idea: specify an alternative!

`sslContext.setKeyManagerFactoryAlgorithm("X509");`

`X509` is also available in Java 7.

I tried by setting explicitly `SunX509` or `KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()` and it barfed so I thought this was the right solution.

And it is actually, to a certain extent. With this change the error disappeared but my SSL setup still did not work, because of unrelated issues, in particular the keystore and certificate passwords were not set correctly.

After fixing those password issues my setup worked again, no need to specify a specific alternative manager, the default was OK.

So to wrap up: if your SSL configuration is all good then you do not need to override the default `KeyManagerFactoryAlgorithm`.